# Inspect Heroku local logs

Tags: heroku, heroku-ci

I have an app that's deployed to production, but I'm also testing it locally.

When I run `heroku logs --tail`, I get the production logs. I can see when I make a request to the webapp and it shows up instantly in the logs.

However, my app on `heroku local` returns me a "500 Server Error." I want to inspect these logs to understand why. However, I can't find these logs. Is there a command like `heroku local logs --tail`?

Comment: Don't you see logs in the terminal, alongside your HTTP 500 error?

Comment: @Chris I don't believe so. I am only seeing when I make successful HTTP requests to the production server.

Comment: If you're talking about your _application's_ logs, they'll be wherever you put them. If you log to a file, look at the file. Heroku _expects_ logging to [be output to `STDERR` or `STDOUT`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log). If you're doing that (I assumed you were), you should see them alongside your HTTP 500 message.

Comment: Still no way to get around this problem?

Comment: @AlexPetralia Do you have `debug` mode on for your app?

like `DEBUG=True` for python flask app

Comment: @AlexPetralia Also, [this](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/123) might help

Answer (score -1):

In order to see logs in IDE or Console use below command

**Local:**

I'm using `Python` script and the same deployed in heroku. I want to run locally by using `heroku local` command and would like to see logs in console but it is not showing logs in `IDE Console`. So for workaround i tried below command and it works well. Now I can see logs in the IDE itself.

E.g. for Python Script:

```
heroku local:run python test.py
```

E.g. for Rails:

```
heroku local:run rails console
```

**Production:**

```
heroku logs --tail --app <app-name>
```